# Issue Upgrading 2sxc Past 12.8.0

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I'm having issues upgrading 2sxc past 12.8.0. I've tried going to 13.12 and to 14.7.4, but I have the same issue. The module installation seems to work fine, but when I go to a page with 2sxc on it nothing loads. It shows this on the page "Something went really wrong in view.ascx - check error logs". It does the same thing when trying to add a new instance to the page. I can't even get to the Admin screen.

Here are three separate entries in the logs after I go to the page with the module on it.

DNN is on version 9.10.2. Any ideas what's going on? I tried installing 14.7.4 on a clean DNN install and it worked fine. Just having an issue with upgrading sites that already have it on and set up.

---

```
08/02/2022 14:15:15
Module Load Exception
host 
ModuleId 433 ModuleDefId 145 FriendlyName Dr M.D ModuleCo 
ModuleId:433
ModuleDefId:145
FriendlyName:Dr., M.D.
ModuleControlSource:DesktopModules/ToSIC_SexyContent/View.ascx
AbsoluteURL:/Default.aspx
DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke
ExceptionGUID:7fcb6220-9d93-4aac-8782-df02a479f8b9
AssemblyVersion:9.10.2
PortalId:0
UserId:1
TabId:80
RawUrl:/About-Us/Our-Providers
Referrer:
UserAgent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
ExceptionHash:V4m6VzNZQyS8zghxe5zRifvuIuk=
Message:Unable to resolve service for type 'ToSic.Eav.DI.Generator`1[ToSic.Sxc.Context.IModule]' while attempting to activate 'ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.DnnModuleAndBlockBuilder'.
StackTrace:
InnerMessage:Unable to resolve service for type 'ToSic.Eav.DI.Generator`1[ToSic.Sxc.Context.IModule]' while attempting to activate 'ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.DnnModuleAndBlockBuilder'.
InnerStackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at ToSic.Eav.DI.IServiceProviderExtensions.Build[T](IServiceProvider serviceProvider) in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Core\DI\IServiceProviderExtensions.cs:line 11
   at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.View.<get_Block>b__5_1() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn\View.ascx.cs:line 32
   at ToSic.Eav.Logging.LogCallBaseExtensions.DoInTimer[TResult](LogCallBase logCall, Func`1 action) in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Core\Logging\Call\LogCallBaseExtensions.cs:line 40
   at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.View.<get_Block>b__5_0() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn\View.ascx.cs:line 32
   at ToSic.Eav.Plumbing.GetOnce`1.Get(Func`1 generator) in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Core\Plumbing\GetOnce.cs:line 28
   at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.View.get_Block() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn\View.ascx.cs:line 32
   at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.View.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<Page_Load>b__1() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn\View.ascx.cs:line 80
   at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.View.TryCatchAndLogToDnn(Action action, LogCall timerWrap) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn\View.ascx.Errors.cs:line 22
Source:
FileName:
FileLineNumber:0
FileColumnNumber:0
Method:
```

---

```
08/02/2022 14:17:45
General Exception
host 
AbsoluteURL /Default.aspx DefaultDataProvider DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvi 
AbsoluteURL:/Default.aspx
DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke
ExceptionGUID:96a99285-dff1-4dad-bca7-3eaf2838d54c
AssemblyVersion:
PortalId:-1
UserId:-1
TabId:-1
RawUrl:
Referrer:
UserAgent:
ExceptionHash:C8Q6+tkICxVB34qGPv1GKvrEviE=
Message:Unable to resolve service for type 'ToSic.Eav.DI.Generator`1[ToSic.Sxc.Context.IModule]' while attempting to activate 'ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.DnnModuleAndBlockBuilder'.
StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at ToSic.Eav.DI.IServiceProviderExtensions.Build[T](IServiceProvider serviceProvider) in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Core\DI\IServiceProviderExtensions.cs:line 11
   at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.View.<get_Block>b__5_1() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn\View.ascx.cs:line 32
   at ToSic.Eav.Logging.LogCallBaseExtensions.DoInTimer[TResult](LogCallBase logCall, Func`1 action) in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Core\Logging\Call\LogCallBaseExtensions.cs:line 40
   at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.View.<get_Block>b__5_0() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn\View.ascx.cs:line 32
   at ToSic.Eav.Plumbing.GetOnce`1.Get(Func`1 generator) in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Core\Plumbing\GetOnce.cs:line 28
   at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.View.get_Block() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn\View.ascx.cs:line 32
   at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.View.InitModuleActions() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn\View.ascx.menu.cs:line 42
   at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.View.get_ModuleActions() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn\View.ascx.menu.cs:line 30
InnerMessage:
InnerStackTrace:
Source:Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
FileName:
FileLineNumber:0
FileColumnNumber:0
Method:
```

```
08/02/2022 14:17:45
Module Load Exception
host 
ModuleId 433 ModuleDefId 145 FriendlyName Dr M.D ModuleCo 
ModuleId:433
ModuleDefId:145
FriendlyName:Dr., M.D.
ModuleControlSource:DesktopModules/ToSIC_SexyContent/View.ascx
AbsoluteURL:/Default.aspx
DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke
ExceptionGUID:1fcebf18-e0a3-439a-b6be-f062eb73a8bd
AssemblyVersion:9.10.2
PortalId:0
UserId:1
TabId:80
RawUrl:/About-Us/Our-Providers
Referrer:https://cozadclinic.com/DesktopModules/admin/Dnn.PersonaBar/index.html?cdv=403
UserAgent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
ExceptionHash:JuER+Ungs3fHFrguNfZECs7N5+8=
Message:Error - can't find 2sxc instance configuration. Probably trying to show an app or content that has been deleted. Or you may have EnterpriseCMS features enabled but are missing the license activation.
StackTrace:
InnerMessage:Error - can't find 2sxc instance configuration. Probably trying to show an app or content that has been deleted. Or you may have EnterpriseCMS features enabled but are missing the license activation.
InnerStackTrace:
   at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Install.DnnReadyCheckTurbo.EnsureSiteAndAppFoldersAreReadyInternal(IBlock block, Lazy`1 appFolderInitializerLazy) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Core\Dnn\Install\DnnReadyCheckTurbo.cs:line 54
   at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Install.DnnReadyCheckTurbo.EnsureSiteAndAppFoldersAreReady(PortalModuleBase module, IBlock block, Lazy`1 appFolderInitializerLazy, ILog log) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Core\Dnn\Install\DnnReadyCheckTurbo.cs:line 34
   at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.View.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<Page_Load>b__1() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn\View.ascx.cs:line 80
   at ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.View.TryCatchAndLogToDnn(Action action, LogCall timerWrap) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn\View.ascx.Errors.cs:line 22
Source:
FileName:
FileLineNumber:0
FileColumnNumber:0
Method:
```

---

This is the new error I got when I upgraded 2sxc after upgrading Plant an App. The entire site is down with this error - this error is all it shows.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The DI Container is not available yet.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Exception: The DI Container is not available yet.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[Exception: The DI Container is not available yet.]
   DnnSharp.Common2.IoC.GlobalContainer.get_RootProvider() +57
   DnnSharp.DnnApiEndpoint.Core.<>c.<.ctor>b__27_4() +9
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +429
   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +158
   System.Lazy`1.get_Value() +79
   DnnSharp.DnnApiEndpoint.Core.<>c__DisplayClass27_0.<.ctor>b__5(ApiMethod data, eLogLevel currentMinLevel) +94
   DnnSharp.Common.Logging.TypedLogger`1.GetCurrentMinLevel(T data) +20
   DnnSharp.Common.Logging.TypedLogger`1.Log(eLogLevel level, T data, Func`1 lazyMessage) +67
   DnnSharp.Common.Logging.TypedLogger`1.Log(eLogLevel level, T data, String message) +95
   DnnSharp.DnnApiEndpoint.Core.App.UpdateWebConfig() +31
   DnnSharp.DnnApiEndpoint.Core.App..ctor() +1774
   DnnSharp.DnnApiEndpoint.Core.App..cctor() +30

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'DnnSharp.DnnApiEndpoint.Core.App' threw an exception.]
   DnnSharp.DnnApiEndpoint.Core.Rewrite.DnnApiEndpointRewriter.CheckConfigHeaders() +39
   DnnSharp.DnnApiEndpoint.Core.Rewrite.DnnApiEndpointRewriter.Init(HttpApplication context) +40
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +522
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +176
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +219
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +304

[HttpException (0x80004005): The type initializer for 'DnnSharp.DnnApiEndpoint.Core.App' threw an exception.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +658
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +89
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +189

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4494.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with Dependency Injection.

It says it can't create a `ToSic.Eav.DI.Generator<ToSic.Sxc.Context.IModule>`.

I can only guess these possible causes, somehow with the upgrade:

1. Either the upgrade had a problem and didn't update/replace all DLLs
2. You may have multiple versions of the Dependency Injection active for various reasons with various modules (some other third-party may have their own DI versions)

I suggest you compare a working install and

1. make sure you manually copy all 2sxc related DLLs
2. Review the web.config for any DI related redirects (often something like Microsoft.Extension...

Comment: I did some more testing and I think it may be related to having Plant an App installed. I'm going to reach out to them as well.

I tried upgrading 2sxc on a few different sites and without PAA, it upgraded fine. On a site that had PAA fully upgraded, it now throws a different error. I'll add it to the original post.

When I only saw the "Something went really wrong in view.ascx" error, I believe PAA hadn't been upgraded yet so I'm assuming that's why it's different.

I looked at the DLL files. If I were to manually pull the 2sxc files over, where would I put them? In "bin" or "bin/2sxc"?

Comment: I also forgot - I have the web config file that I can provide somewhere as well if it would be helpful to see.

Comment: I heard back from Plant an App and they are already aware of the issue and are working on a fix. No ETA as of right now.

Comment: Did they give you more specifics as to what's wrong? Because there were some issues with versions of DI and DNN. It could also be if you go directly to the latest 14 it may then already work?

Comment: My bad, realized you had gone do latest 14 already. If they can give you more details, you can probably sort it out with some web.config redirects?

Comment: I have checked in with Plant an App a few times and they have said you've been working together to try and fix this compatibility issue. Have you made any progress with that or have any kind of estimate on when it might be fixed? We have a site that has some speed issues and we have been told that the 2sxc history table is very large. We hope that upgrading past 12.8.0 might help that but can't do that with PAA installed.

With the history table, do you know if upgrading will help the size of the history table? Or, is there any way to purge the history table right now?

Comment: I can't say much about plant-an-app ATM. The history table can always be purged if you need to do that. In V15 we plan to have a new feature which will compress data in the history-table, so it will be much smaller.

Comment: So just to double check... even if we get it upgraded to 14.12.03 LTS, the history table will still be just as large as it is now? How do we purge it? And/or, do you have an estimate on when v15 will be released?

Comment: This is correct, it remains as is. You can just purge it by using SQL, but users won't be able to undo saved changes any more (History in the edit dialog). 2sxc 15 should be out before X-mas. Note that the feature will be a patrons-only feature.

Comment: Okay thanks! Is that SQL something you can help with if we need assistance? What level of patronage would that be a feature of?

Comment: It will be a patrons-infrastructure (10.-/Month) - for patrons who want to optimize infrastructure aspects. ATM this is the first and only feature that it provides, but we'll add more soon.

Comment: Would that be per site that the module is used on or would the $10/month cover all of our sites where we use it?

Comment: It's per DNN - so if you have multiple sites on a dnn it covers all, if you have one dnn per site each one that needs these features would need to activate the license.

Comment: Okay thanks! Sorry for so many questions - but I see on the website that Patron Perfectionist includes auto converting images to webp. Is that $10/month separate from this since it's patrons-infrastructure? Or would we get that for the $10/month as well as the history compression? I do think we might start with purging the history table - how do we do that? Could you help with the SQL to accomplish that - and what would that cost?

Comment: Can we pay to have you help with the SQL to purge the history table? I think that's the first route we want to take at the moment.

Comment: Sure, just book one hour https://2sxc.org/contact and we'll get it to you in no time...

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! We will do that once we are ready to move forward.

Comment: We are almost ready to have you help with the SQL to purge the history table and are gathering numbers. I noticed that 1 hour isn't an option from your contact form. Is the minimum 2 hours?

Comment: yes, because basically every contact needs some minimal coordination etc.

Comment: Sounds good. I tried submitting the contact form but got an error. "An unexpected error occured while sending. Please try again. If it fails again, please send it by E-Mail." Let me know where to email and I can do that instead.

Comment: @WebServices thanks for the info - we'll check and fix asap. just mail to info@...

Comment: Thanks! Just sent the email off.

Comment: I hate to bother here, but I've emailed twice now with no response. Just wanted to check if my email came through or not. Do you have an ETA for when you might be able to assist with this SQL? What more do you need from me to get started? Where do I send the payment?

Comment: Sorry that I missed it - rest by mail...